# Data from entity framework displayed in javascript/Jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem, and looking for a solution for 2 days
Target : Create/edit client... in HTML build a dialog with  and asp fields with clientIDMode static

```
<div id="divDialog" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="display: none;">
    <div class="DialogFields">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Firstname"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxFirstName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
...
```

In script

```
      $("#btnShowDialog").click(function () {
            openDialog();
});
function openDialog() {
            $("#divDialog").dialog('open');
            $("#divDialog").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        }
```

When I click the button btnShowDialog it works fine... But

Beneath it I have a gridview within it a edit button (asp:Linkbutton) with a event to the codebehind it looks like:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" OnCommand="Edit_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RelationID") %>'
                    runat="server"><img src="../images/Edit-item.png" alt="Edit" /></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

In codebehind take the parameter from commandargument and fire LoadInfo (specific data to all the fields in de dialog).

```
LoadInfo(e.CommandArgument != null ? int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) : -1);
```

but no way I get the dialog open.
I tried

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "openDialog();", true);
```

and

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "openDialog();", true);
```

after this LoadInfo, push btnShowDialog button and it opens the dialog and all data perfect in place.

Also tried the other way around as Directly to Jquery function, get all data loaded and open the dialog. 2 problems, loading in codebehind was not even started before the dialog opens. and I only can get a static function in the codebehind.
A lot of ground to cover for me, but can any body help me out (even for a part). 
...Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to fire some client scripts (openDialog) from the server side, but they wont fire?

Try placing your page in an update panel, lets assume that we name the update panel "MyUpdatePanel". And then refer to the update panel like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(MyUpdatePanel, MyUpdatePanel.GetType(), "MyUpdatePanelScript", "openDialog();", true);
```

Comment: MarzSocks,Thanx for your reaction. With the updatepanel in the whole page it won't work at all. I've placed it around the dialog div's and I have the same functionality as I described.

Comment: sorry first comment was out of time... 
MarzSocks,Thanx for your reaction. With the updatepanel around the whole page (Masterpage in the second content part) it won't work at all. Placing it around the dialog div's , I have the same functionality as I described.

In both cases he runs the scriptmanager line, but the alert('test'); I placed in the function opendialog() doesn't popup.
Directly click the button and it popsup.